# Change multiple div's css based on .filter return results

Tags: jquery, function, filter

I am trying to do a quick text check via Jquery, The text is brought in via an API

```
jQuery(function($){
        $('cite.fn').filter(function () {
        return ["Van", "Motorbike", "Truck"].includes($(this).text());
        }).css('color', 'red');
});
```

HTML:

```
<cite class="fn"><?php echo $json['vehicle']; ?></cite>
```

This works fine, as in turns the text Red - If the response is Van, Truck or Motorbike

However, what needs to happen is, if it is a Van, Truck or Motorbike then this div should show

```
    <div class="citefailed">Sorry we can not offer <?php echo $json['vehicle']; ?> 
Schemes at this time - Then a load of buttons and stuff is inside this div too</div>
```

If the the Vehicle type is a Car then this div shows

```
<div class="cited"> continue the form blah blah</div>
```

What I have tried is

```
    jQuery(function($){
        $('cite.fn').filter(function () {
        return ["Van", "Motorbike", "Truck"].includes($(this).text());
        }).css('color', 'red');
        $(".cited").css({display: "none"});
        $(".citefailed").css({display: "block"});
   });
```

and the css has

```
.citefailed{display:none;}
.cited{display:block;}
```

But this just seems to add Display None to the Cited div and display block to the citefailed div either, whether its a car or a van.

Please see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hatorex1/1/

Can some advise please

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $filtered = $('cite.fn').filter(function () {
    return ["Van", "Motorbike", "Truck"].includes($(this).text());
    });

    $filtered.css('color', 'red');
    if($filtered.length>0){
        $(".cited").css({display: "none"});
        $(".citefailed").css({display: "block"});
    }else{
        $(".cited").css({display: "block"});
        $(".citefailed").css({display: "none"});
    }
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mgwpo0nc/2/

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/akshayrathnavas/1yLv8r7k/16/

I have made a change, with just CSS and a very simple JavaScript change of one word.

```
jQuery(function($){
        $('cite.fn').filter(function () {
        return ["Van", "Motorbike", "Truck"].includes($(this).text());
        }).addClass('red');
});
```

And CSS

```
cite.fn + .citefailed{display:none;}
cite.fn.red{ color: red;}
cite.fn.red + .citefailed{display:block;}
cite.fn.red + .citefailed + .cited {display:none;}
```

You could also do $('.citefailed').show() or hide() based on the conditions.